# Improve code to store large similarity matrix

Tags: python-3.x, out-of-memory, similarity

I have the code below that calculates Jaccard similarities between all pairs of items, called OptionID's. With this code I managed to create recommendations for up to 10 000 items with my 32 GB RAM, but when going above this I get out of memory errors because the matrices generated are too large. More specifically, there are 3 matrices created:

1. viewed_matrix with shape (unique number customers x unique number of items)
2. bought_matrix with shape (unique number customers x unique number of items)
3. similarity_scores with shape (unique number items x unique number of items)

In total I've got around 50 000 customers and 90 000 items. Is there any way to make the code below more efficient so that it can calculate the recommendations using 32 GB ram and at most 6 hours of runtime? I've tried using sparse matrices to store the similarity matrix, but then the actual calculations were too slow since I was no longer able to make the code use vectorization but had to resort to for-loops...

**NOTE:** The input data is of the form:

```
    CustomerID  OptionID    Department  Viewed  Bought
0   0831385695  1659910-01  Womenswear  1       0
1   0831385695  7017300-02  Underwear   1       1
2   0831431176  1645138-01  Home        1       0
3   0831431176  1707888-01  Shoes       1       0
4   0831431176  1720099-01  Home        1       0
```

And the output is of the form:

```
    OptionID    Recommendations
0   7015881-01  7015876-01|7013806-03|7013813-04|7012293-10|70...
1   7012145-01  7012145-02|7012145-03|7012145-08|7012145-06|17...
2   7007931-01  7007931-02|7007931-05|7007931-07|7005624-01|70...
3   7010332-29  7010332-28|7010332-07|7010332-27|7006646-20|70...
4   7017427-01  7017427-02|7018036-01|7017793-01|7018289-01|70...
```

where the leftmost OptionID in the column "Recommendations" is the most similar and the right most is the least. All OptionID's have 50 recommendations each. The code below is completely reproducible if given an input of data as the above.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
import time

def get_similar_items_viewed_bought(item_id, n=50, viewed_matrix=None, bought_matrix=None, department_mapping=None):
    """
    Get n most similar items to the given item_id based on the relationship between viewed items and bought items.
    """
    department = department_mapping[item_id]
    viewed_item = viewed_matrix[item_id].to_numpy().astype(bool)
    similarity_scores = 1 - pairwise_distances(viewed_item.reshape(1, -1), bought_matrix.to_numpy().T.astype(bool), metric='jaccard')
    similarity_scores = pd.Series(similarity_scores[0], index=bought_matrix.columns)
    similar_items = similarity_scores.sort_values(ascending=False)
    similar_items = similar_items[similar_items.index.map(department_mapping) == department].head(n+1)
    similar_items = similar_items.iloc[1:]  # Remove the item itself
    return similar_items

def make_recommendations_viewed_bought(item_id, n=50):
    """
    Make recommendations for an item based on the relationship between viewed items and bought items.
    """
    similar_items_viewed_bought = get_similar_items_viewed_bought(item_id, n, viewed_matrix=viewed_matrix, bought_matrix=bought_matrix, department_mapping=department_mapping)
    
    # Limit the number of recommendations to n
    recommendations = similar_items_viewed_bought.head(n)

    # Concatenate the recommendations into a single string separated by '|'
    return '|'.join(recommendations.index)

# Get unique OptionIDs
unique_option_ids = df['OptionID'].unique()

tic = time.perf_counter()

# Pivot the data frame to create a customer-item matrix for views and purchases
viewed_matrix = df.groupby(['CustomerID', 'OptionID'])['Viewed'].max().unstack(fill_value=0).astype('int8')
bought_matrix = df.groupby(['CustomerID', 'OptionID'])['Bought'].max().unstack(fill_value=0).astype('int8')

# Create a dictionary mapping OptionID to Department so we only recommend items within the same department
department_mapping = df[['OptionID', 'Department']].drop_duplicates().set_index('OptionID').to_dict()['Department']

# Create a new DataFrame with recommendations for each OptionID
viewed_bought_recommendations_df = pd.DataFrame(unique_option_ids, columns=['OptionID'])
viewed_bought_recommendations_df['ViewedBought'] = viewed_bought_recommendations_df['OptionID'].apply(make_recommendations_viewed_bought)
toc = time.perf_counter()

vb_time = (toc - tic)/60

print("----------------------------------------------------------------------")
print(f"Similarity computations completed in {vb_time:0.4f} minutes.")
```